# Managing all app sounds in Lumia 650 DS / Windows 10

Tags: windows-10-mobile, sound, lumia-650

For my newly purchased Lumia 650 DS I have recovered my backup made previously on Lumia 635. To my surprise, most of app sounds that I could managed on Lumia 635 or expected on Lumia 650 are gone.

Currently I can only see / manage (in *System > Notification & actions > Show notifications from these apps*):

- Messaging -- SIM 1,
- Outlook Calendar,
- Outlook Mail.

What I'm missing / expected:

- Messaging -- SIM 2,
- an ability to set phone's default ringtone per SIM, not general,
- an ability to set mail's notification sound also split per SIM,
- sounds for my custom applications.

Is there anything I can do to get these above? Or is Windows 10 much more limited in this area than Windows 8.1 was?

Comment: Let me underline that Windows 10 Mobile turned out to be a complete disaster for me and few days after asking this question I decided to bring my Lumia 650 back to the shop and replace it for some Android-based phone. Thus, I won't be able to provide any additional information or tests on this matter. Thanks everyone contribution and time here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, the notification settings seem rather limited for dual sim phones:

- You can't set different notification sounds / ringtones for each SIM card. :-(
- You can (de-)activate notifications for each mail account separately, but you can't choose different sounds. This has nothing to do with SIMs, though.
- You should be able to set sounds for your other applications in this menu. Maybe you have to receive an initial notification from that app first for it to show up in the list (just a guess)?

It does seem like there are a lot of features missing - not sure what was already available in WP8.1. Make sure to vote for these suggestions in the feedback hub. I'm missing them as well!

Comment: I'm accepting your answer as the best (the only) that can be provided for this a little bit guess-like question. However, Windows 10 Mobile turned out to be a complete disaster for me and yesterday I decided to bring my Lumia 650 back to the shop and replace it for some Android-based phone. Thus, I won't be able to provide any additional information or tests on this matter. Thank you for your contribution.